# What exactly does the chain lightning effect on my Odyn Son do?

Tags: diablo-iii

Last night I found a legendary mace, [Odyn Son](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/odyn-son).

[image: Cropped screenshot showing Odyn Son tooltip]

I'm unclear on how its Chain Lightning ability works, beyond the obvious that there is a 38% chance on hit that it triggers. How is the damage for it determined? How many enemies can it hit, and at what radius? Is it related to the Wizard's Electrocute skill, runed with Chain Lightning? If so, is it actually treated as a skill and thus gains benefit from +Lightning skills gear?

Comment: nice odyn son :)

Comment: The lack of main stat on it made my paper DPS drop about 100k, but overall I seem to be doing more damage than I used to, even without counting the proc. About all I know about the proc right now is that it can crit.

Comment: if you primarily use lightning damage skils, then the 19% will more than make up for the drop of 100k unless your dps is very low.  All procs can crit, but the lack of a helpful weapon damage % number on the orange text makes it hard to figure out exactly how much damage it does.

Answer (score 1):

> 400% weapon damage
>   Will test initial target reports as my data did not indicate that ... but I was tired so who knows (referring to whether or not the Chain Lightning hits the initial target or not)
>   Does NOT benefit from +% lightning damage

The general consensus is that:

- *Yes*, it does do 400% of the original weapon damage
- *Yes*, it does hit the initial target (this was patched in later)
- *No*, it does not benefit from any lightning buffs.

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12504791255)

Answer (score 0):

it deals about 600% weapon damage on each tick, there are 3 tick per proc

Comment: Hi yolo, do you have any sources to back that up with?